# mysql date bug because of subtracting one day

Tags: mysql

I tried to do the following query to subtract one day from the given date:

`DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-04-01') - 86400))`

which returns me 2013-03-30, but it should return 2013-03-31.

If i try to subtract one day of 2013-04-02, i get 2013-04-01 correctly returned.
Is this a date bug in mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug - what you have found is the missing hour in daylight saving time: a thing unixtime and your calculation is unaware of since you calculate with seconds and not days.

This is exactly why DBMS have special DATETIME datatypes - to handle all the specialities in timezones, leap years, leap seconds, daylight savings and calendars.

Let the database do the work for you - here is an easier and better way to get what you want:

```
SELECT DATE('2013-04-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes the assumption that all days have 24 hours. Yesterday, 31st March, had 23 hours in most European countries. To subtract one day you need something like this:

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function?

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2013-04-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

EDIT: No, This is **NOT** a date bug in MySQL.